# Can Python's selenium library play a test case saved as HTML

Tags: python, django, selenium

I'd like to be able to write a Django [LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs#django.test.LiveServerTestCase) which runs a Selenium test that has been saved as HTML using the Selenium IDE.  The code might look something like this:

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver

class TestUserStories(LiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.selenium = WebDriver()
        super(MySeleniumTests, cls).setUpClass()

    def test_registration(self):
        # Note - 'run_html_test' doesn't exist
        self.selenium.run_html_test('selenium/registration.html')
```

This would allow our QA team (who don't speak python) to write tests using the Firefox Selenium IDE and save them as HTML.  Is this possible?

As far as I can tell, HTML is the best format to save the tests in as it allows them to be edited in the IDE later on - exporting to python doesn't allow this and also generates python that needs converting to work with the Django LiveServerTestCase.

Comment: I think the IDE allows exporting to Python. Perhaps this is optimal ?

Answer (score 3):

I started a project myself to build this sort of shim: to wrap existing HTML-based Selenium tests with Python, without having to convert the existing tests. It was for the same reason you state: a (client) testing team wanted to write HTML Selenium tests, but we wanted to run them using Selenium RC. Here's the link:

https://github.com/jpstacey/PySelenese

However, we mothballed the specific sub-project it was built for, so it hasn't had any attention for a long time.

With regards to your specific request, writing a standalone LiveServerTestCase isn't optimal, because you then lose Selenium's idea of having many test cases within a suite, and a suite index.html to define it. PySelenese instead wraps the whole test suite and runs all test cases within it, in the order that the Selenium IDE would run it; but I admit that the code to do that isn't currently very pretty and could be more Pythonic.

But this in theory could do what you want, so feel free to try it out, fork the github project, make your own changes etc. The PySelenese layer currently has limited support for many Selenium commands, but that's fairly extensible.

(Explicit disclaimer: PySelenese started as my own personal Github project.)